# Guaranteed delivery with rabbitmq client Java API

Tags: java, rabbitmq

I'd like to know what is the best way to deal with communication
errors (RabbitMQ crash or network problems, for example), with java
API.

We use the `Channel.basicPublish(...)` method and we would like to
guaranty delivery for each message we send to the broker.

To be more specific, is there a mechanism in the Java client publish
API (before the message is sent to the bus)  that insures that the
message will be delivered (or a callback called when the bus sends an
`IOException`) or do we have to implement this process?

How would you do that?

Comment: Hi, what API version are using ? Thanks

Comment: Thank you walla for your suggestion, yes I know that transaction can probably be an answer, but I didn't want to use such a "heavy" way. We just implemented a ShutdownListener and then we are buffering the messages in a queue, and try to re-establish a connection. When the connexion is ok we send the queued messages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could subscribe to your own messages on the broker, which seems overly complex. As stated by [this answer by Simon MacMullen in the RabbitMQ mailing list](https://grokbase.com/t/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-discuss/10ab9bksga/guaranteed-delivery#20101012zg1g8k15mj7kr33acnhw5fdt94) (moved from OP's question into this answer) **transactions** are an option.:

> At the moment the only way you can guarantee that a publish has gone
>   through is to publish inside a transaction - when the transaction
>   commit completes the message is on disk (assuming durable queue /
>   persistent message). This is a little heavyweight though. In the
>   future we intend to introduce streaming publisher ACKs to do the same
>   job in a more async way.

Since this answer, however, some new options are available in the form of **Lightweight Publisher Confirms**. The official documentation has examples on both the "heavy" transaction approach and the newer streamed publisher confirms:

https://www.rabbitmq.com/blog/2011/02/10/introducing-publisher-confirms/

Comment: I'd recommend stating that this was originally posted by OP as part of their question, and you moved it to an answer.

Comment: @Kerooker not sure whether this type of attribution is welcomed in SO, I would say no... but since it's just a small comment I went with your suggestion

Answer (score -1):

In RabbitMQ there is a method channel.basicAck() which will give you acknowledgment of the message.

Comment: Your solution is for a different problem; he wants to know how to ensure his basicPublish call succeeded, not how to tell rabbitMQ he's handled a message so it can be safely dropped form the message queue.